# Why can't I use the "AND" operator in the same column of a table?

Tags: sql-server

Using this simple table, if I want to see only the records with ProductName 'Chai' and 'Chang' why can't I use the 'AND' operator?

===============================================

```
ProductName // SupplierID //    CategoryID
Chai               1                   1
Chang              1                   1
Aniseed Syrup      1                   2
```

===============================================

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ProductName = 'Chai' AND ProductName = 'Chang';
```

This would return no results although the query would be succesful. I can use the 'OR' operator and the records are returned ok, but why doesn't 'AND' work?

Comment: Use the `OR` operator. A value is either "Chai" *OR* "Chang". A value can't be "Chai" *AND* "Chang" at the same time (quantum funny business aside).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I guess I'm approaching this in the wrong way, but the way I think of it is: I want  the records with ProductName Chai AND Chang to be listed. Any useful resources I could use to get a better understanding of why I am wrong? :))

Comment: For the future, try to read out your query aloud. SQL is very close to the human language. Assuming you want one coffee, would you ask your colleague to get you 'a Latte OR a Cappuccino', or 'a Latte AND a Cappuccino'? It's really as easy as that.

Comment: @oasebones, yes you are going about it the wrong way. Look at the example I gave in the earlier comment. You are asking SQL to get you something. You want both 'Chai' and 'Chang' to be listed. You use 'AND' to narrow down and 'OR' to expand.

Comment: @oasebones: Regarding useful resources to get a better understanding: `AND` and `OR` in the sense used here are called [Boolean operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations). Any time you see AND, OR and NOT in computer languages, they are used in that way.

Answer (score 1):

By writing `WHERE ProductName = 'Chai' AND ProductName = 'Chang'` with `AND` you are requesting the rows which fulfill **both** the condition `ProductName = 'Chai'` and the condition `ProductName = 'Chang'`.
Of course a row cannot have simultaneously two different values for `ProductName` so this query will never return anything.

To obtain all rows with one of those `ProductName`s  you need to write `WHERE ProductName = 'Chai' OR ProductName = 'Chang'` (or `WHERE ProductName IN ('Chai','Chang')`) to request the rows which fulfill **at least one** of the two conditions.

Comment: I am looking at it in the wrong way, but thank you for explaining. It does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To "AND" the result of 2 queries together, use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ProductName = 'Chai'
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ProductName = 'Chang'
```

---

In your particular case, this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ProductName IN ('Chai', 'Chang')
```

but I suspect that's not what you're asking.